# jQuery UI: "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token <" in one environment, but not another

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I have a really simple autocomplete function attached to one of the fields on a CakePHP form. Here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   var availableTags = [<?=$suppliers?>];
   $( "#MsrSupplier" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
  });
});
</script>
```

And here is the code in my controller that pulls the dropdown values from the database.

```
//Dropdown suggestions for autocompleting the Suppliers field
$suppliers=$this->Msr->find('list',array('fields'=>'Msr.supplier'));
$strSuppliers='"'.implode('","',$suppliers).'"';
$this->set('suppliers',$strSuppliers);
```

Field code in my edit.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('supplier', array('type'=>'textbox', 'div'=>false, 
          'name'=>'supplier', 'id'=>'MsrSupplier')); ?>
```

This is working fine in my development environment, which is just a local installation of XAMPP running on Mac OS X. When I start typing a word into the field, I get autocomplete suggestions, complete with CSS formatting. When I push this out to my production server, however, I get the following error when I inspect the field:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The error points to this line in my jQuery code:

```
var availableTags = [<?=$suppliers?>];
```

So, I see the problem, but I don't know *why* it's a problem or what to do about it. The Apache version in XAMPP is 2.4.16. The version on my server is 2.2.3-92 running on CentOS 5. Both environments are running CakePHP version 2.0.5, and the default layouts, which point to my version of jQuery, are the same.

Comment: You likely do not render the PHP. Look in the rendered view-source. Alternative is you have a tag in the array: [<some tag>]

Comment: The Apache and CakePHP versions do not matter as much as the PHP version in this case...

Comment: And there we have a difference. XAMPP version is 5.5.36. Server version is 5.3.3.

Comment: Both criminally outdated ;)

Comment: Yeah, we have a number of legacy applications running on this server. Don't ask. :-D

Answer (score 2):

> *echo* also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration setting enabled.

**http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php**

Your server likely has the option disabled, hence it's being output as is, ie as `<?=$suppliers?>`, instead of being interpreted as PHP.

ps. generally I'd use `json_encode` when passing data from PHP to JS, ie, do not build comma separated, quoted strings in your controller, but pass the query/results to the view as is, and then just do:

```
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($suppliers) ?>; // or <?= when applicable
```

Comment: It appears that short_open_tag is already set to On for default, development, and production.


Point well taken re: using json_encode. How would you suggest I modify my controller code to get the above to work? Right now, if I don't use a comma-separated array, I get an array-to-string conversion error.

Comment: @Chris I'd be suprised if it were really enabled for the problematic environment in question, at least I currently can't think of any other reason for that syntax not being interpreted as PHP. Regarding that error, I can't really tell without knowing where exactly that error is triggered? In the form helper maybe?

Comment: I finally got it to work by explicitly typing "<?php echo" instead of "<?=". So it appears you're right. The short_open_tag setting is either not set, despite what php.ini says, or it's being ignored. No matter, I prefer the explicit, anyway. Thanks for your help!